# Both Schedule C and Schedule C-EZ form for freelance taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

Do I submit both or... which one? (If it is just one) I have been searching for solid information about this for a couple of days... Decided to just throw this question on the stack. Maybe the answer will help others too.

Answer (score 2):

You file one or the other per business, the C-EZ is for simpler situations and can be used if you have profit from your business and meet these criteria per the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/should-i-file-schedule-c-or-schedule-c-ez):

> - Your expenses are not greater than $5,000
> - You have no employees
> - You have no inventory
> - You are not using depreciation or deducting the
>     cost of your home

If any of those criteria disqualify you from using the C-EZ you'll have to file the standard Schedule C instead.